The context needed to make reported speech easy to understand
Direct speech: "Mark cleaned the room when Kate came in"
Indirect speech: He said Mark had cleaned the room when Kate came in
I have one question concering the meaning of my sentence. I think that my original sentence implies that cleaning happened after her arrival. Yet, my second reported version where we use past perfect may suggest that cleaning happende before her arrival. One person on this site explained to me that without context the reported version is ambiguous for natives. You are not sure whether the meaning is that cleaning happened before or after her arrival. I'd like to ask about that  context. What would make you think, when see my reported sentence  that cleaning happened before and what would make you think that it happened after her arrival?

Instead of finding a context to fit the utterance, how about saying what idea you wish to express? There are all kinds of idiomatic options available to you.  For example, "upon Kate's arrival" if you wish to say the cleaning began when Kate arrived or "by the time Kate arrived" if you wish you say that the cleaning had been finished so that a clean room greeted Kate when she arrived. Not my downvote, BTW, but I was considering one because of the ass-backwards find-a-context approach to the question.

I'm the one who encouraged you to think about context, and I repeat my advice. But that's surely for you to work on. I agree with @TimR. You need to practice your story telling. I could do it (as I did in my previous answer). But then it would be my story, not yours. You will only learn by having a go.

For example, Write two stories where you tell us the timing. Story 1 has the cleaning happen before arrival. Story 2 has the cleaning happen after arrival. That's your context. Now, you simply choose the tenses that you think make it clear which story is which. We'll let you know if you got it right!

@user203412 I repeat my comment given in an earlier post. Your basic assumption is incorrect. "Mark cleaned the room when Kate came in" I think that my original sentence implies that cleaning happened after her arrival.  Normally "when" doesn't imply whether it is before or after. So you have to use before or after in place of "when" or use past perfect tense for the earlier action.

@PeterKirkpatrick  1) "and when she finally arrived he was lying in bed dead-tired after cleaning his room" 2)" and when he saw her he rushed to his room to start the cleaning" Correct?

@PeterKirkpatrick One side question. Just to make sure. I could use for instance "knew or believed" instead of "said" when reporting this example, right?

Can you use knew/believed too? Definitely. Asking if you can use those words makes me think you still have a "rules" mindset, is it right or wrong. My point is always, choose whatever best describes your message. If you're talking about what someone said, use that word. If you're talking about what someone knew, use that word.

@PeterKirkpatrick Last question and thank you so  much. Really appreciate that people here help and do that for free.  "I  am the best".  Now if I still think that this person is the best I could report this statement the follwoing way "He said he is the best" but it would also be fine to say "He believed he is the best" or "He thought he is the best". Am I correct?

Yes. No difference with any of those words. See Fumblefingers' comment on this point below.

"Backshifting" of reported speech is usually optional, but if you decide to do it, you should backshift all verbs to retain the same temporal relationships between events / actions...

1: Direct speech:
"Mark cleaned the room when Kate came in"
(implies cleaning started after coming in)


2: NOT BACKSHIFTED
Indirect speech:
He said Mark cleaned the room when Kate came in


3a: FULLY BACKSHIFTED
Indirect speech:
He said Mark had cleaned the room when Kate had come in


3b: PARTIALLY BACKSHIFTED
Indirect speech:
He said Mark had cleaned the room when Kate came in

There's still a degree of ambiguity with both 3a and 3b, because had cleaned tends to imply had already cleaned. But if that's an issue, don't use when - just use before or after to make the temporal sequence clear.

in other words even if we backshift both parts like in 3a it still may convey a different meaning than the original statement that cleaning happened before her arrival, correct? If I add context to either 3a or 3b for instance " and when she arrived he started cleaning windows" it will be clear that  the intended meaning was  that cleaning was supposed to start after her arrival, correct?

Just stop trying to use the word when, which is inherently vague for the context. All scope for ambiguity instantly vanishes if you use before or after.

@FumbleFingerd Thank you. Could we use "He knew Mark" instead of "He said Mark"?

Yes. said, knew, thought, assumed, maintained,... all work the same way in this context.

While the second sentence makes sense and reads fine, I can see where the ambiguity may come in. Commenters are right in saying that this is mostly a matter of the context you place around the sentence, but I understand that’s not your specific question. If you’re particularly looking to improve the specificity of sentences like that, I would explore word choice and word order. How does the meaning change when you move the last phrase to the beginning? Or replace “when” with “once?” Playing around may help you understand the cause and effect relationships here.
